# Apache configuration to present multiple local-only http sites as a single public https site

Tags: http, proxy, https, apache2, reverse-proxy

I'm sure there's a simple solution - but I've banged my head against Apache documentation for what seems like forever... perhaps someone can give me a hint?

On a LAN, I've multiple websites (which, we should assume, have opaque implementations) each operating under a separate domain... and these work just fine.

I want to expose these websites over https, but I only have access to a single suitable IP address - making it desirable to map an /app1/ path to the internal site with an app1 hostname - and a path of /app2/ to the internal site with an app2 hostname - and this is my objective.

I've tried playing with "Apache Module mod_proxy" - and I've tried various combinations of     ProxyPass, ProxyPassReverse and  sections - all with the same problem.  The site at http://app1.example.com/ contains pages that make references to uris of the form "/submit.php" and "/base.css" - which work relative to the multiple http site scheme - but are wrong in the public https scheme where there needs to be multiple roots - identified by the prefix of the path in the public URI.

What's the best way to go about ensuring these URIs are translated properly?  Is mod_proxy appropriate for this sort of task?

Answer (score 0):

You need SNI, server name identification.

What you want to achieve can't be achieve by a web server on its own, it needs the client to be nice and start the encrypted session only after it has sent the domain name, otherwise, it is not possible.

Here is a tutorial, [techrepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/configure-apache-to-support-multiple-ssl-sites-on-a-single-ip-address/987), good luck.

Comment: I (strongly) suspect a misunderstanding. I had hoped to include URIS to illustrate - but stackoverflow.com prevented me from doing this.  I have the sites http://app1.example.com and http://app2.example.com internally.  I want to expose these as https://ssl.example.com/app1 and https://ssl.example.com/app2 repsectively.  This is all about URI translation - which a web server *definitely* can do - in principle... unfortunately, I don't know the magic configuration syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps other people...

My eventual solution was to use mod_proxy to bounce requests from the SSL server to my internal servers... but, for various reasons, it turns out to be far easier to translate the URI in a separate stage where the internal servers are hosted.  I used mod_rewrite to strip the path prefix - and it works charmingly.

It is a pity that there is no obvious way to do this in the configuration of the SSL server (please correct me if I've just overlooked it) and I wasted a lot of time pursuing mod_html_proxy - which was rather strict about the html it would translate.  In any case, it is preferable to translate the selected URIs in Apache than to get Apache to translate entire documents.